# Select all product's last price and if null set to 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables ("Products" and "Prices")

These are the tables:

```
-------------
| Products  |
-------------
| ProdID    |
| ProdName  |
-------------

-------------
| Prices    |
-------------
|     ID    |
| EnDate    |
|ProdID     |
|Price      |
-------------
```

What I want is select all products in Products Table with latest price in Prices Table with 1 condition:

- when prodID not found in prices table, then fill it with 0.

I figure out how to select latest price from prices table only, but I can't figure out how to select all products even though not yet found in price table

This is what I did so far:

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Prices a 
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  ProdID, MAX(EnDate) max_date
            FROM     Prices         
            GROUP   BY ProdID
        ) b ON  a.ProdID = b.ProdID AND
                a.EnDate = b.max_date
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `outer apply` for this purpose:

```
select pr.*, coalesce(pi.price, 0) as price
from products pr outer apply
     (select top (1) pi.*
      from prices pi
      where pi.prodId = pr.prodId
      order by pi.EnDate desc
     ) pi;
```

In this case, the `outer apply` is really just a correlated subquery.  In general, `apply` implements *lateral joins* which an extension of correlated subqueries -- very powerful and often the most efficient way to express particular logic.

Comment: hi, thank you for your quick reply, I tried your query and it worked like a charm! thank you very much.

Comment: Note that scalar aggregates (no `group by`) can use `cross apply` as they always return a result. Vector aggregates (in this case it would be `group by ()`) must use `outer apply` to enforce the `left join` semantic